# Can Black perform a successful freeing break? If yes, what would be his long-term plan after?

Tags: analysis, strategy, middlegame

I have tried to resurrect an old line and use it in my repertoire. Every single time I play it I reach positions similar to this:

```
[Title "White to move"]
[fen "r2q1rk1/pbpnbppp/1p2pn2/8/3PNB2/3B1N2/PPP1QPPP/R4RK1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Usually, engines and most human opponents continue with `c4`. I almost always go for `Re8` + `Qc8`, so I can safely play `...c5` (the Queen is off the d-file so there will be no pressure from a potential `Rd1`, and `Be7` is protected so there will be no `d5` tricks).

### QUESTIONS:

Can we confirm that this is the correct plan, or does Black have better moves at his disposal?

If my plan is viable, how should I proceed when White exchanges on `c5`-> recapture with a pawn or with a piece?

What would be my long-term plan in the resulting position-> minority attack with `...a6` + `...b5` or fighting for `...e5` push?

Thank you.

Comment: This looks like the Rubinstein Variation of the French Defence. If so, it's probably worth adding the french-defense tag.

Comment: I don't see a lot for Black here. I would say Black should mind the d6 square. `1. c4 c5 2. Nd6` and at best Black trades a Bishop for a Knight. It could be annoying.

Comment: @TonyEnnis: After `c4` I can exchange the knights and bishops, I am not obliged to immediately play `...c5`...

Comment: @Stephen: It was Scandinavian defense with `...Qd8`. I am working on a completely new approach for Black...

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: That's interesting. This position does occur in the Rubinstein French though (e.g., Peovic-Tasev, Belgrade, 2012: 1.e4 e6 2.d4 d5 3.Nc3 dxe4 4.Nxe4 Nd7 5.Nf3 Be7 6.Bd3 Ngf6 7.O-O O-O 8.Bf4 b6 9.Qe2 Bb7), so you might find some relevant material in books on the French.

Answer (score 2):

c5 is, by far, the preferred idea and line here, because it not only frees up the light squared bishop, breaks and challenges the d4 pawn, as in some Rubinstein lines, but also allows your queen to visit in e7, and park your rooks on c8 and d8 respectively.

It is by far, in terms of breaks, the most effective, and does not allow white the luxury of a kingside attack.

Therefore, as white, it would be beneficial, tactically, to park your a-rook on d1 to prevent c5 and then try to play on the d-file with doubled rooks and c3 (to prevent counterplay).

Comment: Upvoted. I like the idea of parking the queen on `e7` but can not see how will I achieve that, can you provide a specific plan for that?

Comment: C5, dx, nx, nx, by, re1, qe7 is one line. Or you can just take and park it in two extra moves